# Vaadin JPAContainer - no transaction is in progress

Tags: jpa, jboss, vaadin, jta, jpacontainer

I've been trying to use Vaadin JPAContainer with a JTA datasource in JBoss, but I keep getting this error when committing a FieldGroup: *"no transaction is in progress"*

Here's my persistence.xml

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="Pagamento">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/Pagamento</jta-data-source>  

      <class>br.com.edu.entidades.Usuario</class>

      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"></property>         
         <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"></property>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"></property>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"></property>  
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
      </properties>

   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm also using a custom EntityProvider in order to support JTA:

```
public class EduEntityProvider extends MutableLocalEntityProvider<Usuario> {     

    private EntityManager em = HibernateUtils.entityManager;

    public EduEntityProvider() {
        super(Usuario.class);
        setEntityManager(em);

        setEntitiesDetached(false);
        setTransactionsHandledByProvider(false);
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    protected void runInTransaction(Runnable operation) {
        super.runInTransaction(operation);
    }    

}
```

The Entity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario extends EduPersistentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @VisivelTabela(false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="senha")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name="matricula", unique=true)
    private String matricula;

    gets... 
    sets...
}
```

If I set the transaction handled by provider to true

```
"setTransactionsHandledByProvider(false);", i'll get the error 
" A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()".
```

If anybody could point me to a working example or just give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong, would be much appreciated.

Comment: How `super.runInTransaction(operation) method` look like ?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use JPAContainer? For any serious usage I suggest to use a @Stateless EJB to hide the JPA stuff from the UI layer. Then just pass list of your entity objects to UI components with BeanItemContainer. Or if you care a lot a about the performance of your application, check out Viritin add-on and its [lazy loading features](https://vaadin.com/web/matti/blog/-/blogs/more-on-lazy-data-binding). Those perform better than JPAContainer (both CPU and memory) and are easier to use.

Comment: @wypieprz, super.runInTransaction(operation) yields the same result... but thanks

Comment: @mstahv, I did think about it, but that would break my whole application, instead i'm controlling the EntityManager manually and passing to the JPAContainer, i know it's not the best thing to do, but it solved the problem  and didn't really require a lot of refactoring.

Comment: Not using JPAContainer or using Java EE application server? It should be possible to gradually move from JPAContainer to Facade+BeanItemContainer/Viritin style architecture. EJB would just make the DB access bit easier than with plain EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

The following error is self explanatory:

> A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

In other words you cannot call `EntityTransaction.getTransaction()` when JTA is specified by the data source in the persistence.xml.

---

Below are general rules for Transaction Management so you can follow one of them and adopt the provider according to your needs.

- resource­-local transactions (Java EE / Java SE)

  - application­-managed entity manager

    ```
     @PersistenceUnit(unitName="...")
     EntityManagerFactory emf;

     public void foo() {
         em.getTransaction.begin(); //explicit begin
         ...
         em.getTransaction.commit(); // explicit commit
     }
    ```
- JTA transactions (Java EE only)

  - application­-managed entity manager (bean-­managed transactions)

    ```
     @PersistenceUnit(unitName="...")
     EntityManagerFactory emf;
     EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

     @Resource
     UserTransaction tx;

     public void foo() {
         tx.begin(); //explicit begin
         ...
         tx.commit(); // explicit commit
     }
    ```
  - container­-managed entity manager via EJB (container­-managed transactions)

    ```
      @PersistenceContext(unitName="...")
      EntityManager em;

      @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) //default
      public void foo() {
          // implicit begin
          ...
          // implicit commit
      }
    ```
  - container­-managed entity manager via CDI (container­-managed transactions)

    ```
      @PersistenceContext(unitName="...")
      EntityManager em;

      @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED) //default
      public void foo() {
          // implicit begin
          ...
          // implicit commit
      }
    ```

Comment: i get that, but the problem lies in the Vaadin's JPAContainer.
The vaadin FieldGroup is trying to persist the entity, it's not my code.

Comment: I can hardly believe it. Your example looks pretty much the same as Matti Tavhonen's [Using JPA Container 2.0 in a JEE6 server](https://vaadin.com/web/matti/blog/-/blogs/using-jpa-container-2-0-in-a-jee6-server) blog post. Have you tried to inject EntityManager instead of HibernateUtil's assignment and initialize the class as specified in the [reference example](https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/incubator/jpacontainerjee6/src/main/java/org/vaadin/jpacontainerjee/EjbEntityProvider.java) ?